# Adding COLLATE to Spring Data JPA Query

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have a simple JPA Repository with both derived and native queries. Now, I have to (or at least I want to) specify collation for a given query, something like:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    @Query(value = "select * from users u order by u.firstname collate :language", nativeQuery = true)
    List<User> findAllUsersCollate(@Param("language") String language);

}
```

As far as I'm concerned, derived queries do not support collations.

The problem arises when I try to use parameters to specify the collation name. Using hard-coded collations

```
@Query(value = "select * from users u order by u.firstname collate hun", nativeQuery = true)
```

works fine, but not suitable.

Note: In the example, 'hun' is a custom collation name with hu_HU locale.

I think the problem is with parameter substitution. Is there a way to specify collation for a given query using one of [Spring Data JPA Query Methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods)? If not, how can I create a query that accepts a collation parameter and translates into a valid SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

Just a follow-up post with a possible solution I came up with in the end.

I used custom JPA repositories described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations). For example, the base repository is UserRepository, the custom is UserRepositoryCustom and the corresponding class implementing it is UserRepositoryCustomImpl. The queries are defined in the following style:

```
select * from users u order by u.firstname collate _COLLATION_
```

UserRepositoryCustomImpl, apart from implementing the UserRepositoryCustom interface, extends an AbstractCustomImpl class where the *COLLATION* placeholder replacement happens. In this way, any other repositories that need collations can implement this abstract class as well.

```
public abstract class AbstractCustomImpl {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Value( "${...}" )
    private String defaultCollation;

    @Value( "${...}" )
    private String hungarianCollation;

    private static final String COLLATION_REGEX = "_COLLATION_";
    private static final String HUNGARIAN_LANGUAGE_CODE = "hu";

    public Query createCollatedQueryFromQueryString(String queryString, Locale locale, Class<?> resultClass){
        queryString = replaceTokensWithCollationString(queryString, locale);
        return entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryString, resultClass);
    }

    private String replaceTokensWithCollationString(String queryString, Locale locale){
        if(Objects.equals(locale.getLanguage().toLowerCase(), HUNGARIAN_LANGUAGE_CODE)){
            return queryString.replace(COLLATION_REGEX, hungarianCollation);
        } else {
            return queryString.replace(COLLATION_REGEX, defaultCollation);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in UserRepositoryCustomImpl, make use of the createCollatedQueryFromQueryString method.

```
    @Override
    public List<User> findAllByOrderByLastnameAscFirstnameAsc(..., Locale locale) {
        Query query = createCollatedQueryFromQueryString(FIND_BY_QUERY, locale, *.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
```